# SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above in

Tags: php, postgresql, enterprisedb

I get an error when I try to connect to the Postgresql server with PHP, and I get an error like this one:

> Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above in

I use EnterpriseDb, and is `pg_connect();` in my code and I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Update your PostgreSQL client shared library (`libpq.so`).

Comment: how did you install postgres/libpq/postgresql-client on your PHP machine?

Comment: for me I am using xampp, I re-installed it and the error got fixed

Answer (score 2):

--- windows 7 64 / postgresql 13 ---
In my case:
I did download libpq.dll from **https://www.exefiles.com/en/dll/libpq-dll/**
then i did replace old **libpq.dll** at php directory whit the latest downloaded and
it did work !

Comment: You just replaced newer version with older version 9.6

Answer (score 1):

I got that error when I enabled only one extension `extension=php_pgsql.dll` in `php.ini`, I tried again uncomment `extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll` , and it's worked well for me