# Unable to connect Postgres database from CakePHP 2.x

Tags: database, postgresql, cakephp, pgadmin-4

I am using the pgAdmin 4. When I am trying the connect to Postgres from cakephp using the default database configuration like below:

```
public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Postgres',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'postgres',
        'password' => 'test1234',
        'database' => 'mydatabase',
        'prefix' => '',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
    );
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error: [MissingConnectionException] Database connection "Postgres" is missing, or could not be created.
Exception Attributes: array (
  'class' => 'Postgres',
  'message' => 'SQLSTATE[08006] [7] SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above',
  'enabled' => true,
);
```

please help me to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "requires libpq version 10 or above", what version do you use?

Comment: Please read the error message. Does this answer your question? [SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58454622/scram-authentication-requires-libpq-version-10-or-above-in)